# Make tar archive only files without directories (equivalent of zip -D -j)

Tags: linux, tar

I want to tar (and gzip) files without directories and do not store directory paths. I want only flat files in my archive.

For example if I'll do something like this:

```
tar -czf archive.tgz /home/another/path/*
```

Then I'll have files with paths in my archive:

```
home/another/path/file1
home/another/path/file2
home/another/path/file3
```

But I'd like to have only this:

```
file1
file2
file3
```

This is an equivalent of zip's `zip -D -j` command.

For simplicity's sake lets assume that there are no subdirectories inside `/home/another/path/` - it contains only files.

I tried wit `-C` option but it didn't seem to work. With command like this:

```
tar -C /home/another/path/ -czf archive.tgz *
```

The tar was trying to archive files in current dir instead of the dir passed to `-C`. I'm using `(GNU tar) 1.19`.

Comment: If I understand your question correctly then this [SO] question [How do I tar a directory of files and folders without including the directory itself?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/939982) should help.

Comment: @DavidPostill I admit I tried `-C` but it didn't seem to work. `*` tarred files in current dir instead of the dir passed to `-C`. Any idea why?

Comment: No idea - I'm not a Unix guru -- I just know a little and how to search :/

Comment: @SiliconMind any luck trying the answer below? If so it might help others if accepted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following:

```
find . -type f -printf "%h\n%f\n" | xargs -L 2 tar -rf /tmp/files.tar -C
```

or some variation depending on your needs. One should consider security when executing this command. And if you're willing to have "./" before the filename, the following might be a little more secure:

```
find -type f -execdir tar -rf /tmp/files.tar {} \;
```

or

```
find -type f -execdir tar -rf /tmp/files.tar {} +
```

Comment: `find /home/another/path -maxdepth 1 -type f -execdir tar -rvf /root/tmp/tar/files.tar {} \;` Worked for me. Thanks. I've added `-maxdepth 1` to not descend into subdirectories of `/home/another/path`.

Comment: I think the last command is missing a \ in front of the +